# Use Object_id as indices in python (Cosine Similarity)

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, cosine-similarity

I am using pandas data frame which have '_id' as object id of the News Article.
The problem is that when i use '_id' as indices, it shows an error

**TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3108             try:
-> 3109                 return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
   3110             except IndexError:

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()

pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()**
[image: df.head() Result]

Here is my code

```
indices = pd.Series(ds.index, index=ds['_id']).drop_duplicates()


   def get_recommendations(id, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):


    idx = indices[id]


    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))


    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)


    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]
    sc=[]
    for count,ele in sim_scores: 
       sc.append(ele)




    movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    ff = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
    ff['A']=ds['_id'].iloc[movie_indices]
    ff['B']=ds['title'].iloc[movie_indices]
    ff['C']=sc


   return ff

get_recommendations('4fd2b43e8eb7c8105d8a67e8')
```

Comment: What is `indices`?

Comment: updated my code in the post 
Just added online above the function

Comment: Please update your question with a sample (`.head()`) of the dataframe, and the full error traceback

Comment: Updated the post